# How to properly run migrations and seed a docker MySql DB using Entity Framework Core

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core

I implemented database migrations in my ASP.NET core solution as it's recommended in the following issue: [Pattern for seeding database with EF7 in ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3070)

My solution is setup for working on linux docker and the application depends on a MySql container that is configured in the docker compose file and setup on the first run.

The migrations run in the Startup.Configure method as:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
    context.EnsureSeedData();
}
```

But running the application for the first time always throws the following error:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Then if I wait some seconds and re-launch the debug session the code executes without problem and the first-run data is there.

Is there a way that it could wait for the DB server to be ready before running the migrations?

EDIT:

If I change the migration method for the one in this question: [Cannot get the UserManager class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027388/cannot-get-the-usermanager-class)

instead of the previous error I get this one:

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that it could wait for the DB server to be ready before running the migrations?

In your Program.Main, you could add code that attempts to open a connection to MySql, and loop until the connection opens successfully.

For example:

```
public static void Main()
{

    MySqlConnection connection;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=mysql; Server=server;User ID=user;Password=password");
            connection.Open();
            break;
        }
        // ex.Number = 1042 when the server isn't up yet, assuming you're using MySql.Data and not some other MySql implementation
        catch (MySqlException ex) when (ex.Number is 1042)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Waiting for db.");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // ... continue launching website

}
```

Comment: Really? Any solution that recommends a Thread.Sleep gets down voted

Comment: You're totally missing the nuance of why it's necessary.